# APEX: How to change region template to one of a different theme?

Tags: oracle, templates, themes, oracle-apex

I use oracle apex 4.2 and the "Builder Blue - 2"-Theme.
To get a bit of coloring into my page, i would like to use the report-region template of the red theme - 1.
Is it possible to import just the region template of another theme into your active theme?

I tried to change the color of that region via CSS, but it didn't work out well since there are images referenced in the CSS files, e.g. "bg-region-blue-r.gif" for the rounded corners of that region.
Let me know if i missed something on the CSS-part, which would also make it work.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy a template from one theme to another by:

1. Import the red theme into your application. You don't need to switch to it though.
2. Go to Shared Components -> Templates
3. Click **Create**
4. Select **Region**, click **Next**
5. Select **As a Copy of an Existing Template**, click **Next**
6. Select the same application from the list, click **Next**
7. Select the red theme for "Copy From" and your current theme for "Copy To"
8. In the list, find the template you wish to copy and set "Copy" to "Yes"
9. Click **Copy Region Templates**

Comment: thanks for your answer, that's what i was searching for. though, my region won't display as expected.
[Screenshot](http://imgur.com/CH9BRUN) "Test" is the Title of my region here.

Comment: Template used for the Region is: "copy of reports region, red template" (thats how i named the copy). Could this be a compatibility error? 
via Firebug I inspected the page and it loaded "/i/themes/theme_2/css/theme_4_0.css" but not "theme_1/css/theme_4_0.css" which my template-copy is from. Could this be a reason?

Comment: You might need to edit the template to pick up the correct CSS.

Comment: Problem solved.
Added the link "/i/themes/theme_1/css/theme_4_0.css" to the first page's CSS "File URL" and know everything works fine. 
Thanks again Jeffrey

Comment: Even though it's probably bad for the performance to load a whole new theme's css, I currently have no other solution.